# Leetcode 132 pattern question - can I use a monotonically increasing stack?

Tags: python, debugging, stack

For https://leetcode.com/problems/132-pattern/solutions/

i < j < k

I know that the solution out there uses mono decreasing stack, but I am wondering why I can't use a mono increasing stack. I would want to maximize K and for the max K to be on the top of the stack. I can keep track of the min value up until the given element on the stack as well.

I have been stuck for hours - can someone please explain why my code doesnt work?

```
    stack = [(nums[0], nums[0])] # num, min value
    curMin = nums[0]

    # mono increasing stack
    for num in nums[1:]:
        if stack and num < stack[-1][0]:
            if num > stack[-1][1]:
                return True
        else:
            stack.append((num, curMin))
        curMin = min(curMin, num)
    
    return False
```

PS. I am not passing this test case:

[1,4,0,-1,-2,-3,-1,-2]

Comment: Please summarize the Leetcode problem here, not just a link.

Comment: You never remove anything from the stack. Don't you need to backtrack?